# Xamarin Maps Crashing in Android Emulator

Tags: c#, android, xaml, dictionary, xamarin

I'm having a bit of an issue with the Xamarin.Forms.Maps and the exceptions are not propagated up into the debugger in a meaningful way to help me diagnose the issue.

I can get it to work, everytime I reinstall Visual Studio. It will work a couple times then eventually it will crash 100% of the time as long as the Map item is in the xaml. I am not remaking the project between running, just reinstalling Visual Studio. I'm running Visual Studio 17 Community.

The error just says:

'Your app has entered a break state, but there is no code to show because all threads were executing external code (typically system or framework code).'

I have a valid API Key, and even if I comment out ALL code relating to the Map it eventually happens other than the Xaml that will create it. If I reinstall visual studio I can manipulate the map the first few times I invoke the debugger before it fails.

I wish I could give more information, but I'm pretty new to Xamarin development so I'm a bit unsure why reinstalling Visual Studio fixes the issue, temporarily. Any insight would be much appreciated, as I've spent many hours trying to diagnose and reinstall, but have no idea what the issue could be given the error doesn't really say much of anything. I'd love to provide more information if someone has more ideas for me to check out.

In general, it also fails to deploy eventually also : / which is why I tried an install originally. I'm not sure if this is related.

MainPage.xaml.cs

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Plugin.Geolocator;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Plugin.Geolocator.Abstractions;

namespace LawnDroneCompanion
{
    public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
    {
        private List<Position> RecordedPositions = new List<Position>();

        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void StopGeoLocatorListening()
        {
            BeginTrackingRoute.Text = "Begin Tracking";
            BeginTrackingRoute.BackgroundColor = Color.Green;
            CrossGeolocator.Current.StopListeningAsync();
        }

        private async void StartGeoLocatorListening(object obj, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (CrossGeolocator.Current.IsListening)
            {
                StopGeoLocatorListening();
                return;
            }

            BeginTrackingRoute.Text = "Stop Tracking";
            BeginTrackingRoute.BackgroundColor = Color.Red;

            CrossGeolocator.Current.DesiredAccuracy = 10;

            ///This logic will run on the background automatically on iOS, however for Android and UWP you must put logic in background services. Else if your app is killed the location updates will be killed.
            await CrossGeolocator.Current.StartListeningAsync(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1), 1, true, new Plugin.Geolocator.Abstractions.ListenerSettings
            {   
                ActivityType = Plugin.Geolocator.Abstractions.ActivityType.Other,
                AllowBackgroundUpdates = true,
                DeferLocationUpdates = true,
                DeferralDistanceMeters = 1,
                DeferralTime = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1),
                ListenForSignificantChanges = true,
                PauseLocationUpdatesAutomatically = false
            });


            Position StartLocation = await CrossGeolocator.Current.GetLastKnownLocationAsync();
            //MyMap.MoveToRegion(Xamarin.Forms.Maps.MapSpan.FromCenterAndRadius(new Xamarin.Forms.Maps.Position(StartLocation.Latitude, StartLocation.Longitude), Xamarin.Forms.Maps.Distance.FromMiles(0.2))); 

            CrossGeolocator.Current.PositionChanged += GeoLocateHandler;
        }

        private void DrawNewLocation(Plugin.Geolocator.Abstractions.Position position)
        {
            if(RecordedPositions.Count > 1000)
            {
                return;
            }

           RecordedPositions.Add(position);
           //MyMap.MoveToRegion(Xamarin.Forms.Maps.MapSpan.FromCenterAndRadius(new Xamarin.Forms.Maps.Position(position.Latitude, position.Longitude), MyMap.VisibleRegion.Radius));
        }

        private void GeoLocateHandler(object sender, PositionEventArgs e)
        {
            Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>
            {
                DrawNewLocation(e.Position);
            });
        }
    }
}
```

MainPage.xaml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:LawnDroneCompanion"
             xmlns:maps="clr-namespace:Xamarin.Forms.Maps;assembly=Xamarin.Forms.Maps"    
             x:Class="LawnDroneCompanion.MainPage">
    <ContentPage.Content>
        <StackLayout>
            <StackLayout VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
                <!-- If I comment this out it works, this comment isn't in my real code -->
                <maps:Map x:Name="MyMap" IsShowingUser="True" MapType="Hybrid"/>
            </StackLayout>
            <Button x:Name="BeginTrackingRoute" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" Text="Begin Tracking" Clicked="StartGeoLocatorListening" BackgroundColor="Green" TextColor="WhiteSmoke" BorderRadius="0"/>
        </StackLayout>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="1.0" package="com.companyname.LawnDroneCompanion" android:installLocation="auto">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="25" />
    <!-- Google Maps for Android v2 requires OpenGL ES v2 -->
    <uses-feature android:glEsVersion="0x00020000" android:required="true" />
  <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_MOCK_LOCATION" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_LOCATION_EXTRA_COMMANDS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <!-- Allow the application to access Google web-based services. -->
    <!-- Google Maps for Android v2 will cache map tiles on external storage -->
    <application android:label="LawnDroneCompanion.Android">
        <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY" android:value="{IMAGINE-MY-KEY-HERE}" />
    <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
  </application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: I have tried your code , but I can't get crash. Refer to this https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/troubleshooting/troubleshooting/#Diagnostic_MSBuild_Output to get more information